# Return array of objects from function - VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, function

I need to "return" an Array of Objects from a function that I created using VBA. When I try to set the function as the array it gives me an error message, saying

> Object is required.

I am not very used to VBA, and I can't fix this. Here is the function code:

```
Function sortedList(listRange As Integer, tempList() As ship) As ship
   Dim temp As ship
   Set temp = Nothing

   For i = listRange - 10 To 1 Step -1

       For j = 2 To listRange - 10
            If tempList(j - 1).Arrival > tempList(j).Arrival Then
                Set temp = tempList(j - 1)
                Set tempList(j - 1) = tempList(j)
                Set tempList(j) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    'return tempList - how?
    Set sortedList = tempList

End Function
```

`Ship` is a "class" that I created. `tempList` is the array of objects from class `ship` that I need to return from the function `sortedList`.

The function works, it's just the return part that I can't make work.

Thanks for the help. If more information is necessary let me know!

Comment: Did you try to remove type specification of function output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare the function to return an array

```
Function sortedList(listRange As Integer, tempList() As ship) As ship()
```

and then assign the result without `Set`

```
sortedList = tempList
```

Comment: Ok, it worked! Now, how to assign what I return from that function to a variable outside od the function? Like, Var1 = sortedList(param1, param2)

Comment: Exactly like that. :)